# Setting background of searchResultsTableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've a problem. I trying to set the background of an searchResultsTableView.
Into my SearchViewController implementation, during the viewDidLoad, I want to set the background either of my self.tableView and of self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView. I do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Search";

    UIColor *customColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:252.0 blue:227.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = customColor;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = customColor;
}
```

After this, I've the tableView with my custom light-yellow color but, when I tap the search bar, and the tableView was replaced by searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView, this results white.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = customColor; will change the color after you click the "search".. this will not change background while you editing text.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use this method .. it will call when you start searching..

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"]];
}
```

[image: Screenshot of search results table view with custom background.]

Comment: I've add this to my controller:


`- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
 tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:252.0 blue:227.0 alpha:1.0];;
}`
But nothing changed :(

Comment: I've put an NSLog("%s", __FUNCTION__); entry before coloring the tableview, and I see into my log window:`-[SearchViewController searchDisplayController:didLoadSearchResultsTableView:]`. So I think the function is called.

Comment: See attached image.. not really sure what's wrong then.. do you have tableView declared in side class with same name.. as tableView in this case.. any warnings ?

Comment: I've no warning. Now I think there is some problem by setting custom colors. I will try with an image file, and tell you if it's solved. - edit: Yeah, with the background image everything working well. So I think there is a bug with custom colors defined by RGBA. Thanks

Comment: what if I want to put a UIImage in the background of the SearchDisplay controller.... what is the solution??

Answer (score 2):

That i-Blue's solution with **didLoadSearchResultsTableView** works just fine. However I define search result background color this way:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.searchDisplayController.
    searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor =
        [UIColor blueColor];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

So far no problems.

Comment: Try to do a search, then cancel the search and search again.  I suspect the background color will be different than you expect.

Comment: I tried, no problems. Maybe I have some additional setup to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with UITableViewStyleGrouped-type background was white. This works for me (inspired by D-Griffin answer but added one line):

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    tableView.backgroundColor = color;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reply to Matteo in comments, so I'm doing it here. 
Besides, it might be useful for further reference.

If you want to add a color specifying the RGB code, there's one simple trick.

The documentation says the UIColor method initWithRed:green:blue:alpha accepts CGFLoat values, which are values between 0.0 and 1.0

so Instead of doing `UIColor(Red:255.0, green:252.0, blue:227.0, alpha:1.0)`, which won't work, do the following :

```
let red:CGFLoat = 255/255
let green:CGFloat = 252/255
let blue:CGFloat = 227/255
UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue,alpha:1.0)
```

this works perfectly well inside the searchDisplayController(UISearchDisplayController:controller, didLoadSearchResultsTableView UITableView:tableView)

this is swift, but you could translate this in obj C easily enough